# How can I optimize this query that has an inner select query for date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

The query is:

```
select sum(value) 
  from TAB 
 where TimeStamp=
     {
         select max(TimeStamp)
           from TAB where col1=12 and col2=18
     }
   and col1=12 and col2=18;
```

I am trying to improve it by eliminating the sub query if possible.

Comment: Oh, the sql-server/oracle RDBMS, I love that one. Please choose the correct RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(value) 
  from TAB 
 where col1=12 and col2=18
 group by TimeStamp
 order by TimeStamp desc
 limit 1
```

Comment: @aF. limits the result set to **one** record (just the one with greater TimeStamp)

Comment: @HLGEM: it wasn't tagged as sql-server or oracle or tsql before. :-S